# How to get ReadLine and then transfer the input to a variable

Tags: c#

I seem to be really struggling with programming at the moment. I am quite new to this but I've had a little while without doing any so I was wondering if anyone could help me out with the following code.

```
Player player1 = new Player(name here);
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
            string playername1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Bassically I want what the user input I read to go where it says (name here) as this will then say within the game of battleships "player "the players name" enter your coordinates.

Thanks for your help ;)

```
 Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
            string playername1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
            Player player1 = new Player(playername1);

            Gameboard battleships = new Gameboard();
            battleships.CreateRandomShips(5);
            while (true)
            {
                battleships.DisplayBoard();
                Move move;
                do
                {
                    move = player1.GetAMove(battleships);
                }
                while (!battleships.AreCoordinatesValid(move));
                battleships.Attack(move);

                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
                string playername2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                Player player2 = new Player(playername2);

                Gameboard battleships2 = new Gameboard();
                battleships2.CreateRandomShips(5);
                while (true)
                {
                    battleships2.DisplayBoard();
                    Move move2;
                    do
                    {
                        move2 = player2.GetAMove(battleships2);
                    }
                    while (!battleships2.AreCoordinatesValid(move2));
                    battleships.Attack(move2);
                    break;
```

Comment: Consider to watch or read some tutorials, about basics of C# such things are fundamental.

Comment: Thanks for your help you guys are really helpful I appreciate it. I do have some resources but I struggle to get my head round some of their teaching methods. I learn better by seeing it done rather than it being described (I suppose I should look for some stuff with examples.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just a constructor for player taking name as parameter, you could do

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
Player player1 = new Player(System.Console.ReadLine());
```

if you have an empty ctor :

```
Player player1 = new Player();
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
var name = System.Console.ReadLine();
player1.Name = name;
```

Comment: Hi, Im not sure if this is all you require. But that's pretty much it for both players.

Comment: I've included it at the top of the page, if that isn't enough then I will post anything else you need, again thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `ReadLine()` before you instantiate the `Player` class.

```
string playername1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
Player player1 = new Player(playername1);
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
```

C# also has a `var` keyword, to reduce the amount of typing necessary during coding. Since the compiler knows that the `Player()` constructor returns a `Player` object, you can simply use:

```
var player1 = new Player(playername1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your player class to take a string as an argument. Then just switch place of your lines, like this and pass playername1 as a parameter:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
            string playername1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
            Player player1 = new Player(playername1);
```

Comment: Hi, I have now used this however it does not seem to store player 2's name. Any idea as to why it is doing this?

Comment: I'm gonna need a bit more code to figure that out. I don't see anything about a player 2 here and I have no ide what your player class look like.

Answer (score 0):

As most people suggest, you have to instantiate the player name before constructing the `Player` object.

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
string playername1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
Player player1 = new Player(playername1);
```

However I just wanted to add that you don't have to introduce a variable if your only purpose is to use it in one call. Changing it to this looks like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BattleShips. What is your name?");
Player player1 = new Player(System.Console.ReadLine());
```